# AJAX: How to get array on multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a json which is . I just want to get specific data which is

`obj['contacts']['name']`

How can i get

`obj['contacts']['name']`

name on **Contacts** array

[image]

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: uri,
  cache: false,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data) {
    for (var obj in data) {
      console.log(obj['contacts']['name']);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `obj` is _key_. Iterate over `data.contacts` and get `name` from it.

Comment: `obj.contacts.map(function(item) {return item.name});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case this is how you want get name from `contacts`

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: uri,
  cache: false,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data) {
    if (!data.contacts) return;
    var names = data.contacts.map(function(dt) {
      return dt.name;
    });
    console.log(names);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just enumerate the returned object "contacts" property:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: uri,
  cache: false,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data) {
    data.contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
      console.log(contact.name);
    });
  }
});
```